# Can't find logical error with my switch compare Python program

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple Python program that will hook to a little microcontroller alarm project I'm working on.  The microcontroller is connected to eight switches.  It outputs a binary value based on the switch state over a serial port.

I'm trying to write the python program decoder and am using hard coded values to check my logic.  Here's what I've written:

```
switches='11011101'
currentstate = {}
prevstate = {}


def initswitches():
        for x in range (0,8):
                name = "switch" + str(x)
                currentstate[name] = switches[x]
                prevstate[name] = switches[x]

def setswitches():
        for x in range (0,8):
                name = "switch" + str(x)
                currentstate[name] = switches[x]

def checkswitches():
        for switch in range (0,8):
                name = "switch" + str(switch)
                if ( currentstate[name] != prevstate[name]):
                        print name + " value changed to " + str(switch)


initswitches()

for y in range (0,2):

        setswitches()
        print "Loop" + str(y)
        print "Switches:"
        print switches
        print "Current state:"
        print currentstate
        print "Previous state:"
        print prevstate


        checkswitches()

        prevstate = currentstate
        switches='01001001'
        print
        print
```

and here's the output:

```
Loop0
Switches:
11011101
Current state:
{'switch3': '1', 'switch2': '0', 'switch1': '1', 'switch0': '1', 'switch7': '1', 'switch6': '0', 'switch5': '1', 'switch4': '1'}
Previous state:
{'switch3': '1', 'switch2': '0', 'switch1': '1', 'switch0': '1', 'switch7': '1', 'switch6': '0', 'switch5': '1', 'switch4': '1'}

Loop1
Switches:
01001001
Current state:
{'switch3': '0', 'switch2': '0', 'switch1': '1', 'switch0': '0', 'switch7': '1', 'switch6': '0', 'switch5': '0', 'switch4': '1'}
Previous state:
{'switch3': '0', 'switch2': '0', 'switch1': '1', 'switch0': '0', 'switch7': '1', 'switch6': '0', 'switch5': '0', 'switch4': '1'}
```

As you can see, I am able to set the binary values to each switch correctly to current state, but for some reason previous state is always matching current state.  Loop0 shows expected behavior, but Loop1 should have previous state matching what was output for Loop0 .  I cannot find where I am setting previous state to match currentstate before the checkswitches function is called.  Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Incidentally, it seems like your code is a bit overcomplicated. All you need is a mutable, indexable sequence to store switch state, not a dictionary mapping. `current_state = list(switches)` should work nicely. Then, you can access switch `i`'s state with `current_state[i]`. You can make copies of the state by using list slicing (`previous_state = current_state[:]`, or by calling the list constructor on it `previous_state = list(current_state)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
prevstate = currentstate
```

redirects the variable `prevstate` to equal the `currentstate` dict. `prevstate` is now literally the same object as `currentstate`.
Doing so makes all changes to `currentstate` affect `prevstate` too.

To fix, make `prevstate` a copy of `currentstate`:

```
prevstate = currentstate.copy()
```

Alternatively, you could update `prevstate` with the key-value pairs in `currentstate`:

```
prevstate.update(currentstate)
```

This second option is perhaps preferable since you would be creating (and subsequently throwing away) fewer objects.

Comment: @dinky: You can check it by putting currentstate["test"]=True before the loop. You will observe that prevstate becomes current state (because the assignment prevstate=currentstate copies the references not the content)

Comment: Just want to mention `copy.deepcopy` as well for people doing this type of thing with more complex structures.

Comment: You can also do `prevstate = dict(currentstate)`.